# chop string(arguments passed by user)

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

suppose the user passed 5 arguments(`$1` `$2` `$3` `$4` `$5`), how do I cut off the first two arguments(`$1` `$2`) and I only want the last 3 arguments

`awk '{print $3,$4,$5} < $@'` 
what if I don't know how many arguments passed but I do not want the first two arguments

I can not use shift since I also need info from $2, what should I do then?

I ran into this problem when tar files in bash script when the user might use regular expressions like `*.txt` and the shell will automatically convert that into `file1.txt` `file2.txt` (suppose there are only two `.txt` files)

Comment: Have a look at `shift` (see `help shift`).

Comment: `foo="$2"; shift 2`?

Comment: @Socowi if I use shift it will delete what is in $2 but I also need info from user

Comment: See Cyrus' comment. You can store the parameters in variables before you shift.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# note: indexing starts at 0

# 0: script name
# 1: arg 1
# 2: arg 2

# this will skip the script name, arg1 and arg2
echo "${@:3}"
```

Comment: if I do something like `tar -cvf $2 ../source/${@:3)` the indicator became red for the following code, is this normal

Comment: @Bob You used a close parenthesis rather than curly brace. Also, are you trying to prepend "../source/" to *each* argument (starting with `$3`), or just to `$3` (and `$4`, `$5`, etc don't get the prefix)? Finally, you should put double-quotes around parameter and variable references, including `$2` and `$@`.